# TFS checkout overwrite option for cruisecontrol.net?

Tags: tfs, cruisecontrol.net

I'm trying to find ways to use ccnet with TFS2008 (and/or 2010) with the [overwrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx%28lightweight%29) option

Is there a way short of checking out the CCnet source and patching it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we checked out the source and built one that allows `<overwrite>true</overwrite>`

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not experienced in TFS this should be easy enough using the executable task:

```
<task>
  <exec>
    <executable>C:\YourPathToTFS\tf</executable>
    <buildArgs>get itemspec /overwrite</buildArgs>
  </exec>
</task>
```

**EDIT**: This would be a more general approach:

```
<sourcecontrol type="vsts">
  <server>http://theurl:8080</server>
  <project>$\YourProject</project>
  <force>true</force>
</sourcecontrol>
```

The `<force>`-option seems to correspond to TFS `/force` switch which combines `/all` and `/overwrite` switches.

Comment: This solution requires we dump all the options from the `<sourcecontrol>` block of ccnet, and move all those separated concerns into the build file, yes? Then convert all the readable easy to edit configurations in the sourcecontrol block into a big ugly properties conglomerate?

Comment: If You're looking for a more general approach inside the sourcecontrol block take a look at the edit of my answer

Comment: is there no way to avoid the /all parameter so we only get /overwrite. getting the entire source everytime seems futile.